# Check if App is Using DevAPP

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionic-devapp

I’m trying to figure out how to check if my Ionic app is running on DevAPP (DevAPP is a testing platform that runs your app locally on your device).

This is important because I’m using a plugin that is not available in DevAPP, so it crashes the app. I want to be able to perform some kind of check to see if the app is being run with DevAPP. And, if it is, I just won’t call the code for the unavailable plugin.

I’ve tried checking `platform.platforms()`, but it just says “mobile,android,phablet,mobileweb”. Those don’t seem to suggest that DevAPP is running.

Another possible solution would be a way to check if a plugin is installed. I tried just checking if the injected variable was truthy `if( this.fcm )`, but this still crashes the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right. Well, I wasn't able to figure out how to specifically check within the code whether or not the app is currently running on DevAPP. But I did manage to find a solution to my problem. It was actually pretty straight-forward.

Since the native plugin I was trying to use returns a promise, I just used the .catch() method available on promises:

```
this.fcm.getToken().then( token => {
    console.log( 'token: ', token ); //@DEBUG
})
.catch( error => { // Catch error that FCM is not available in DevAPP and web
    console.log( 'Error Getting FCM Token: ', error ); //@DEBUG
});
```

This can also work with Observables by processing the error response option:

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe( 
    data => {
        console.log( 'data: ', data ); //@DEBUG
    },
    error => {
        console.log( 'Error Subscribing to FCM Notification: ', error ); //@DEBUG
    }
);
```

After implementing this code, my app no longer crashed while running in DevAPP.